# Struts2 dispatch request to another application

Tags: struts2, embed, dispatcher

I'm using Struts 2.1.8.1. I have a requirement to embed some pages from another server on my own app, so the users will access to them through my application, without accessing directly the other server. My idea is to have a package definition for that, so any access to that package would be redirected to the internal server.

```
<package name="eco-marketing" namespace="/marketing" extends="eco-default">
    <action name="*">
        <result name="success" type="dispatcher">
            <param name="location">http://myotherserver:8080/test/{1}</param>
        </result>
    </action>
</package>
```

But it does not work, I got a Error 404--Not Found, so I suppouse is not as easy as it sounds. Any ideas on how to do this?

TIA

Comment: dispatcher only processes jsp's it can not be done from struts.xml (unless you create your own custom result type).

Comment: It seems so. so I guess the best option is to implement a custom action that uses a HttpClient for that.

Comment: Yes, but like you point out it does seem be be the job of a result and it wouldn't be very hard to implement... it is just easier to get the action working first. I think it could be useful to a lot of people.

Comment: Well, I have the Action almost ready. It is very simple, for each resource the browser needs to get, it sends a request to my app, which launchs the same request to the back-end server, and send the result back to the client using a result type stream. there is some issues with remapping the URL on the HTML returned by the back-end server(all references should be relative to avoid this issue). Also, the post of parameters needs some work, otherwise it works fine. Only thing is that I've switched to another project, so I don't have time to finish it. If anyone is interested, just contact me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that you are accessing just html, then see: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

I would recommend creating an action in that package to do the work for you, and use the value of the parameter to get the required data.

You probably already know but an iframe in the consumer action will make this easier to use than trying to parse what you need out.

After you have that figured out, if you decide to create a custom result type, please post it back to us here it would be very interesting.

An example of a custom result type can be found here (4th code block from the top): http://siriwardana.blogspot.com/2008/12/creating-custom-result-type-struts-2.html

Comment: I am not sure about this particular situation but isn't [Web Services](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/ENUNCIATE/A+Rich+Web+service+API+for+Struts+2) is usually the way to communicate to another application

Comment: Well he just wants to get a web page off a remote machine and include the content in his own. It does not sound like the OP has the ability to change the remote server so all he can do is consume the pages. There are some security issues in doing this... as if the remote site decided that it did not like this practice it could put some malicious JS in the page, since you have lifted the whole page into your own domain the script can now manipulate anything on your page. If the OP wants to show a page as is, an iframe is best. Otherwise data should be parsed from the page to be safe.

Comment: hmm very true thats a complete explanation